# Is there a better way to sync mysql databases between developers?

Tags: mysql

When you have developers who aren't using a centralized sql server it can be a pain to keep up with changes.  It's getting frustrating trying to make and merge alter tables between people on laptops.

Is there a better way to do this?  Maybe some free mysql synchronization tools for developers?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about synchronizing _schema changes_ or _data changes_?

Comment: keep sql scripts in the version control repository and give each developer an instance

Comment: One thing i've done is have a file called something like "_Alter_.sql" that you have your changes in (like altering/inserting/deleting values and tables) and then have that on a repository or something like the the cloud (if you trust that) for everyone to have access to (give them an instance of it or access to it) and then they can just run those changes on each of their computers

Comment: We pass schema changes and test data.  It's not a lot of data usually only a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

I used Liquibase "http://www.liquibase.org/" on several project and was very happy with it!
You define the schema change in a format independant from the database so it is also possible to change database later. The best practice is to include the liquibase files in you version control system. And commit them with the code that depend on the new schema.

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you need a migration management system of some sort. There's several of these, from the one that ships with Ruby on Rails, to others for NodeJS and Python. Pick one, standardize, and you'll be in much better shape.

Migrations are basically patches to your schema and are typically given a serial number to describe what order they should be added in.

For an example, see [Node DB Migrate](https://github.com/kunklejr/node-db-migrate).